Remove Attachment From PHP Form Handler
I have a webform on my site with many data fields, including a file upload field.
I have another page on my site which requires a much simpler form, so I used the longer form, and have scaled it back to just the user name and user email.
I have tested the new (simple) form, and it works great.
However, the file attachment language is still in the form handler, and still sends an empty attachment.
I need some help stripping out all the file attachment language.
I have tried to strip those parts myself, but with each attempt, the form fails to send.
I have included the working version of the form handler with the file attachment language still included.
Form Handler:
<?php

$name = $_POST['userName'];
$email = $_POST['userEmail'];

$composition =

"\r\nName: "           . $name .
"\r\nEmail Address: "  . $email;

$subject ="Email Subject here";

$fromname ="$name";
$fromemail = "$email";

$mailto = 'receiving@email.com';

//The Content Action

$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

// A random hash will be necessary to send mixed content

$separator = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Carriage return type (RFC)

$eol = "\r\n";

// Main header (multipart mandatory)

$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;". $eol. " boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . 
$eol;

// $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;

$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

// Composition action

$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $composition . $eol;

// The attachment action

$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;". $eol. " name=\"" . $fileName . "\"" . 
$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;

$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;". $eol . " filename=\"" . $fileName."\"" . $eol . 
$eol ; 
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

header('location: /somefolder/somepage');

?>


Simply remove the lines related to adding attachment(s) in your code
On the other hand, better revise your code by:

use utf-8 charset instead of iso-8859-1
Add the line $subject= "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject).'?='; so that the subject line can also include utf-8 characters
If you would like to send message with HTML code , then change text/plain to text/html in the following line

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset='utf-8'" . $eol;

So the revised code will be (I added some non-English characters to show the effect) :
<?php

$name = $_POST['userName'];
$email = $_POST['userEmail'];

$composition =

"\r\nName: "           . $name .
"\r\nEmail Address: "  . $email;

$subject ="Email Subject here 中文字";

$fromname ="$name";
$fromemail = "$email";

$mailto = 'receiving@email.com';

//The Content Action

$content = file_get_contents($tmpName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

// A random hash will be necessary to send mixed content

// $separator = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Carriage return type (RFC)

$eol = "\r\n";

// Main header (multipart mandatory)

$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset='utf-8'" . $eol;


$body .= "This is the message 中文字 " . $composition. $eol;


$subject= "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject).'?=';    

mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

header('location: /somefolder/somepage');
?>

